# Open Preview for iPhone and SD card

Tags: iphone, photos, preview, import

Is there a way to automatically open Preview whenever I plug my iPhone in my Mac to import the photos? Also want to do this when connecting my Nikon SD card. I just hate this new Photos app, I prefer to use Preview to import.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Connect your phone.
2. Open **Image Capture** from your Applications folder.
3. In the bottom-left corner of the Image Capture window, select "Preview" where it says "Connecting this iPhone opens:"
4. Repeat while your Nikon SD card is connected.

[image: Screenshot of Image Capture window]

Comment: I just love you.

Comment: @sanjuro8998 lets stay professional here :)